# Screen flickers while using Minecraft Fabric

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

[image: It looks way worse than it does here.]

The graphics on the terrain, etc. flicker on and off, while the mobs seem to be just fine, as well as my player model and items. I have Fabric installed, and I only face this issue while it's downloaded. Why is this occurring?

Comment: support for 3rd party modifications is off topic. fabric is a mod and a mod loader

Comment: @Topcode I dont think this is really technical support

Comment: @Penguin then what is it?

Comment: @Topcode support

Comment: @Penguin for a mod. about seemingly irregular behavior.

Comment: Display flickering is definitely a technical issue, and it's clearly caused by a mod. It's not like Fabric gives the player a custom status effect that is exhibited by brightness switching rapidly. It's definitely tech support.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've set Minecraft to use the wrong GPU making it fail to shade the terrain. Switch from Dedicate Graphics to Integrated Graphics, or the other way around (usually it's this).